# how to change browser search text font color?

Tags: browser

I am using ubuntu 11.10. 
The Google Search bar font color of my firefox browser is almost white with a white background. This occured after i installed Eye Of Gnome Theme.

How to change the font color?

Answer (score 0):

You can create **~/.mozilla/firefox/PROFILE/chrome/userContent.css** with the following in it :

```
input {
-moz-appearance: none !important;
background-color: white;
color: black;
}
textarea {
-moz-appearance: none !important;
background-color: white;
color: black;
}
```